# Manipulate Strings

Tags: java, string

I am trying to find the most repeated word in a string, with this code:

```
public class Word 
{
    private String toWord;
    private int Count;

    public Word(int count, String word){
        toWord = word;
        Count = count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str="my name is neo and my other name is also neo because I am neo";
        String []str1=str.split(" ");
        Word w1=new Word(0,str1[0]);
        LinkedList<Word> list = new LinkedList<Word>();
        list.add(w1);
        ListIterator itr = list.listIterator();
        for(int i=1;i<str1.length;i++){
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                if(str1[i].equalsTO(????));
                else
                    list.add(new Word(0,str1[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I compare the String from the String Array `str1` to the String stored in the linked list and then how do I increase the respective count.

I will then print the string with the highest count,
I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: What language are you using? Format your code. Is this homework?

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?  Why didn't it work?  Be more specific.

Comment: I am trying to compare the input string with one in the linked list if it matches I increase the count of the string,my question is how do I compare with the string in the linked list

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest use HashMap instead of linked list.

`Iterate through the string.

 For each word,

 Check if the word is in the Map,

 If it is there increment count and

 Otherwise insert with count 1`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store each word to a list, perhaps a long with a count variable that indicates how many times that word has been used.

For each word, increment the count if it's already in the list, or add it to the list if it's not.

Comment: Ya i knw the algorithm but how do i compare if the string is in the linked list or not,please look at my code

Comment: The way you add every word from the string to the array is working against you because it may contain duplicates. As I mentioned, add each word to the list one by one. If the word is already in the list, then increment the count instead of adding it again.

Answer (score 0):

C#? You may try to use LINQ GroupBy and then Count or Max - very straightforward.

Comment: I am using java,and this is not homework.I just need to get used to string operations with linked list

Comment: Well, you didn't specify any tags and the basic structures of Java and C# are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Multiset<String> words = HashMultiset.create(Splitter.on(" ").split(input));
```

Then

```
String topWord = words.isEmpty() ? null 
    : Iterables.get(Ordering.natural().immutableSortedCopy(words), 0);
```

You can get the frequency of the top word with `words.count(topWord)`.

Comment: How do i include Multiset and Hashmultiset classes?

Comment: You need to download and install the Google Guava libraries, http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/list. Extract it and put the Guava JAR in your classpath. Then you can import them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use some regex over here like

```
    final String str = "my name is neo and my other name is also neo because I am neo";

    final String[] arr = str.split (" ");
    final Set <String> set = new HashSet <String> ();
    for (final String word : arr) {
        System.out.println ("arr " + word);
        set.add (word);
    }

    String preWord = "";
    int preCount = 0;
    for (final String word : set) {
        System.out.println ("----------------");

        final Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile ("\\b" + word + "\\b");
        final Matcher m2 = p2.matcher (str);
        int count = 0;

        while (m2.find ()) {
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println ("preCount " + preWord + ":" + word + ":" + preCount + ":" + count);

        if ((preCount < count)) {
            preWord = word;
            preCount = count;
            System.out.println ("assigning word " + word + ":" + count);
        }
    }

    System.out.println ("result " + preWord + ":" + preCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Commons StringUtils [org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) to get the count.

```
String str="my name is neo and my other name is also neo because I am neo";
// Make a unique list (java.util.Set) of words.
Set<String> stSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));
int sz = stSet.size();
int[] counts = new int[sz];
Map<Integer,String> matches = new HashMap<Integer,String>(sz);
int i = 0;
for (String s : stSet) {
   // saves the individual word count in a sortable array.
   counts[i] = StringUtils.countMatches(str,s));
   // saves the word count and the word in a HashMap for easy retrieval.
   matches.put(counts[i],s);
   i++;
}
Arrays.sort(counts);
int max = counts.length - 1;
System.out.println("The the word with the most occurrances is: "+matches.get(counts[max])+", the number of occurrances is: "+counts[max]);
```

Comment: I know I didn't use linked list in my answer. If you really need to use linked list, I suggest you change your requirements and not do it.